# HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'name' is not present

Tags: java, изображения, jsp, spring-mvc

Заполняю форму "Товар", загружаю изображение, выбераю категорию, жму на кнопку и падает такое ерор. Пересмотрел код много раз, помогите найти ошибку!

```
ServiceImpl
@Transactional
public void addProduct(String name, String description, String city, double price, MultipartFile file, String category) {
    Product product = new Product(name, description, city, price);

    try {
        product.setImagePath(file.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        product.setImagePath(new byte[1]);
    }
    product.setCategory(categoryService.findCategoryById(Integer.parseInt(category)));
    productDao.save(product);
}

 Controller
   @RequestMapping(value = "/createNewProduct", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String createProductPage(Model model) {
    List<Category> allCategories = categoryService.findAllCategories();
    model.addAttribute("categories", allCategories);
    return "product-new";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/newProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createProduct(@RequestParam("name") String name,
        @RequestParam(value = "description") String description, @RequestParam(value = "city") String city,
        @RequestParam(value = "price") double price, @RequestParam(value = "imagePath") MultipartFile file,
        @RequestParam(value = "category") String category) {
    productService.addProduct(name, description, city, price, file, category);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

JSP

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="newProduct" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputLogin3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"
                    placeholder="Name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description"
                    placeholder="Description">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputName3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">City</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city"
                    placeholder="City">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputSecondname3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Price</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price"
                    placeholder="00.0">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPhone3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Image</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="imagePath"
                    placeholder="Image">
            </div>
        </div>

            <c:forEach items="${categories}" var="category">

                <input type="radio" name= "category" value="${category.categoryId}">${category.name}
            </c:forEach>
<div class="register_button">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
        </div>
    </form>
Maven 
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.36</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
        <version>0.3m</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Form Validation using Annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
В сервлет-контекст.хмл надо прописать bean для того, чтобы Spring дал добро загружать файлы. 
<bean id="multipartResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
<property name="maxUploadSize" value="2000000"></property>
</bean>
```